# How to pixelate a set of lines into a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, line, pixel

It looks a very simple question.
There are many lines available as their two endpoints.
The question is **how to discretize them into a matrix**. Then the matrix can be used for image processing purposes.
At the following figure example lines (yellow) and their corresponding pixelated demonstrations are shown.
A piece of code in any language would be of great help and strongly recommended and of course is in advance appreciated.
Note that performance and accuracy are very important factors.
Also as demonstrated each point of line must have only one pixel (i.e., element of matrix) associated.

[image]

Comment: I've answered your specific question below, but I wonder what your application for this is?  I've used myself as a form of primitive 2d collision detection.

Comment: @luserdroog I made it in Excel!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Just to share with great readers and visitors there are some pseudo-codes there could be easily implemented. I used the last one (complete solution:optimization) and it worked very well.