# To pixelate geometric primitives

Tags: algorithm, pixel, computational-geometry

It is necessary to have a matrix representation of a **set of geometric primitives** (i.e., line, curve, circle, rectangle, also their filled forms). For simplicity you may suppose we are dealing only with lines, so the answer is already on [[**SO**]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397247/how-to-pixelate-a-set-of-lines-into-a-matrix). Rectangles therefore could be easily pixelated. For the rest of primitives however two questions appear to me:

> **1) How to pixelate a curve including circle (~closed curve)?
>
>   2) How to pixelate a filled simple / complex shape (rectangle, multi-patch)?**

The simplest way (currently in use) may be utilizing a visualizing library (such a `MatPlotLib` for `Python`) to save the result (a map of geometric primitives) as a pixelated image on disk (or RAM) and then reuse it for the purpose of interest. Apparently, this method can handle any complexity since in background whatever it (the visualizer) does the output is a `2D image`, i.e., `2D matrix`. Some serious problems however emerge in this application:

> **1)** the procedure is very slow!
>   **2)** the procedure is not standard but heavily dependent to the setting of the visualizer, that is often the low-level configuration is impossible or difficult to be set for visualizer. In other words, the black box being used lacks controlling on the procedure as required.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is called "scan conversion" of geometric primitives.

For line segments, you already know about [the Bresenham algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

There is a similar one for circles, a bit trickier (as regards handling of the endpoints).

General curves is a broader topic. You can think of conics, splines or hand-drawn. One approach is to approximate them with a polyline.

To fill polygons, there is a scanline algorithm available (consider a sweeping horizontal line and fill between the intersections with the polygon outline).

To fill arbitrary shapes, an option is to draw the outline and use seed filling (from a given internal point).

You will find relevant material at http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis681/cis681Ch5.html